# Short story where a human and alien fighter have to battle it out to decide the outcome of a war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Back in high school, around 1990, we read half of a short story where, to end a war, an alien and human have to battle it out. They are in an area that is separated by an invisible division so that they can't get to each other but they can see each other, and there is a tree on each side.

I got to where the human was sitting under the tree, trying to figure out what to do next. I've always wanted to read the rest of it, but this is all I know - I can't remember the title or author.

Comment: Duplicate of this one https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259822/i-read-the-book-around-1982-sci-fi-galactic-battle-between-human-and-alien-set/259825#259825 (it's Arena by Fred Brown)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/101945/man-vs-alien-from-an-old-anthology/101946#101946 for an accepted (but rather bare) answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for this for over 30 years. Didn't think I'd ever find out how it ends